# fatal error: Array index out of range with many tap Swift

Tags: swift, tableview, segue, tap, indexoutofrangeexception

When I tap only one time on one of cell in table view, it works perfect to another view controller. But if I tap twice, triple or more times on the cell quickly before move to another view controller.

An error of array index out of range would be shown and highlighted "`let labelTitle = self.resultsTitleArray[indexPath.row]`". I tried to use `self.view.userInteractionEnabled = false` before `performSegueWithIdenitifier` and `self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true` after `performSegueWithIdenitifier`. But still doesn't work.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "moreDetail"){
        let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ProductDetailViewController

        let indexPath = self.resultsTable.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let labelTitle = self.resultsTitleArray[indexPath.row]
        viewController.labelTitleText = labelTitle
        self.resultsTable.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("moreDetail", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: I guess you're using the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method to throw your segue, can you please share your code regarding this method?

Answer (score 0):

you need to check if indexpath is nil

```
if(indexPath == nil){
return
}
```

and to be 100% sure it works you can also do

```
if(indexPath == nil || indexPath.row >= self.resultsTitleArray.length){
return
}
```

Comment: indexPath can never be nil, so comparison is not allowed.

Comment: Did you try to check the other parameters of the second if statment?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the multiple touches from the TableView so that
those events will not be fired by setting the multipleTouchEnabled to false.

```
self.tableView.multipleTouchEnabled = false
```

Comment: I tried to put the code in viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear and viewWillAppear, I still can multiple touch the cell and cause the error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try removing `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and going to your storyboard and Control-dragging from the cell to the segue view controller. Name that segue "moreDetail." See if the segue fires immediately before you have a chance to double- or triple-click the button.